# Create PHP webservice to respond to android Application in JSON format 

Tags: php, android, web-services, joomla1.7

Previously i have used restful wcf webservices to get the data from server.But now i have to access PHP webservices.Using WCF restful webservices I used to get data as :

```
{ 

1,books, //0th index  

2,toys,  //1st index . . .

}
```

but wen i am getting data from php webservice it is coming as a single array similar to the format shown below

```
[

1,            // 0th index

books,        // 1st index

2,            // 2nd index

toys,         // 3nd index

.

.

.

]
```

Please tell me is is not possible in php to create a json array as it is created in WCF restful services ??
Above shown formats are only symbolic representation of the actual data what i am getting from webservices.

Joomla 1.7.3 and virtuemart 2.0 is used by php developer to develop webservices and also web app is created in using 1.7.3 and virtuemart 2.0 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to modifiy the dimension of the array accordingly to what you want, somthing like this I presume:

```
$test = array('1' => array('books', 'foo', 'bar'),
              '2' => array('toys', 'foo', 'bar'));

print (json_encode($test));
```

This code will return the indexed values:

```
{"1":["books","foo","bar"],"2":["toys","foo","bar"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example of an [Android / PHP webservice](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/).

Comment: Thanks Hiren for answering but i have seen that link i need an explaination on can it be done in php ?? if yes then how can we do it ??